# Is there any way to solve the issue in unity: ErrorCS0234: The type or namespace name 'Database' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase'

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do some projects about the Firebase real-time Database and unity3D, the data from sensor will be upload to Firebase Database, then unity will read data from database. But the unity3D doesn't work well. and the info from unity is: ErrorCS0234:The type or namespace name 'Database' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase'.(targeted in the line "using Firebase.Database")

I reimport the Firebase.database unity package, and it also doesn't work.

Here are my C# code:

```c#
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
while (true)
    {
      // string[] V = new string[100];
        string Url = "https://.....firebaseio.com/.json";
        var httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        var response = (HttpWebRequest)httprequest.GetResponse();
        var stream = new            StreamReader(response.GetRequestStream()).ReadToEnd;
        var firebasevariable = JObject.Parse(stream);
        string GSR =     firebasevariable["ValueOfGSR"].ToObject<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(ValueOfGSR);    
  }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: The dll might be misconfigured for your project.  If you select it and then look in the inspector, you should be able to rule out whether or not that's the problem.  [Check out this doc for info on how those settings work](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. I think I got it.